# Do a-bit-for-bit copy of ESXi 5.1

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

i have an ESXi 5.1 installed on a HP server that includes several virtual machines and virtual appliances.I looking for a way that i can Do a-bit-for-bit copy of entire ESXi 5.1 and deploy it on another HP server with exactly same hardware, i need all of my virtual machines and virtual appliances work correctly just like the original ESXi host...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can connect both system with help of switch.

1. Install **ESXi 5.1** on another system
2. You need to have shared storage for both machine.
3. Create a Network for Vmotion.
4. Do the Vmotion or Storage Vmotion so that you can migrate all of your data to a new machine.

After vMotion you will have the same data as on first server.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by do the Vmotion or Storage Vmotion?

Comment: i really appreciate for your respond, but this doesn't address my problem because when i move virtual machines to the new ESXi host some IDs associated to virtual machine get change and all licenses get lost.i looking for a way to do copy or movement without any change in hardware fingerprint of virtual machines .